# Bash: If line begins with >

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want an `if`/`then` statement in Bash and I can't seem to get it to work. I would like to say "If the line begins with `>` character, then do this, else do something else".

I have:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[$line == ">"*]]
    then
        echo $line'first'
    else
        echo $line'second'
    fi
done
```

But it isn't working.
I also tried to escape the ">" by saying:

```
if [[$line == ^\>*]]
```

Which didn't work either.
Both ways I am getting this error:

```
line 27: [[>blah: command not found
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest using `=` rather than `==` -- otherwise you're in habits that will bite you if you're ever using `[ "$foo" == "$bar" ]` on a pure POSIX shell (where the operator is `=`, not `==`).

Comment: @mbratch, you're mixing RE syntax (where the `^` is appropriate) with pattern syntax (where anchoring is implicit).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wasn't trying to make that part correct and it wasn't my point. I was just illustrating using the op's example. My point was about the spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spaces are needed inside `[[ and ]]` as follows:

```
if [[ "$line" == ">"* ]]; then 
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: One gotcha here -- if the first `echo` fails for some reason (stdout closed?), the second one would be run (which is moot with echo, but maybe not with other code). Best not to treat `foo && bar || baz` as a ternary, since it's not.

Comment: ...and no, it _isn't_ necessary to quote the left-hand side of `[[ $foo = "$bar" ]]`; that's one of the key advantages to using `[[ ]]` rather than `[ ]`.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I know that pitfall about ternary operation, let me edit it keep `if/else`.

Answer (score 2):

This attempt attempt uses a regex:

```
line="> line"
if [[ $line =~ ^\> ]] ; then 
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

This one uses a glob pattern:

```
line="> line"
if [[ $line == \>* ]] ; then 
    echo "found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: Vastly less efficient (spawning a subprocess rather than using a native comparison), and what is the `&& $?` supposed to achieve? `$?` is always non-empty, whether `0` or `1`, and so that test has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy better? ;)

Comment: Better. Not a fan of using a regex where a glob will do, but this is certainly no longer a -1.

Comment: I'm more used with regexes. Also it is more readable and maintainable than the `&& ... ||` or combination answers. (imo) ;)

Comment: Using *both* `&&` and `||` in a compound command is typically a code smell, since its behavior isn't equivalent to that of a native ternary operator, but using only one or the other is idiomatic shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy :) Thanks. Have added a version that uses a `glob` pattern. I have to admit that using `grep` (my first attempt) here was really not acceptable. It was good that you mentioned this..

Answer (score 1):

Spacing is important.

```
$ [[ ">test" == ">"* ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ "test" == ">"* ]]; echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
if grep -q '>' <<<$line; then
   ..
else
   ..
fi
```

using grep is much better :)

Comment: What's your case? Why do you think so?